# iPhone Browser Live Testing

Tags: iphone, testing, browser

I'm using win7.
and i have website which i want to test it with iPhone browser environment.
which it's use most flash (jISFR).

this is the website i talking for,

http://www.hamuranalodge.com/

may you can see menu navigation is using flash jSIFR, which it's seems not work in iPhone, and want to fix it. of course i need iphone Testing for it.

Is there somebody know how i can test it with iphone browser?
may there is a software can do it?
or a website give service like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a perfect solution but you might be able to test it on the Android browser instead. The SDK runs on all major OSs and is free to download and install. Just make sure that flash support is turned off. I'm pretty sure iPhone and Android both use WebKit so you should get similar behaviour on both.

Comment: yes you right, it's seem all OS handphone have same capability in running Flash

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [iPhone simulator](http://developer.apple.com/) if you have access to a Mac.

Comment: If he's wanting to test a Flash website in the iPhone browser, he may as well use a housebrick... Right now, Flash does not run at all in the iPhone browser.

Comment: Nope, i didn't have a mac here. I Use Windows 7

Comment: Sadly, your options are pretty limited. If you're looking at Flash testing then bigiain has summed up your options fairly well.

Answer (score 0):

There are sites like this:

http://www.testiphone.com/

but this one doesn't work very well, at least not for this particular request. Go there and point it at www.worldsbk.com - it renders the Flash block on the top right hand side just fine on my desktop computer (Firefox3 Mac OS X), but have a look here:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/bigiain/5037577763/

to see a screen grab of that page from my iPhone... Note the big grey block where the flash bit should be...

Comment: Now that you've given us the url, here's the actual site in my iPhone browser: http://www.flickr.com/photos/bigiain/5038661860/ it's entirely functional, it's just that the menu text is big and blocky. If this were my site, I'd just style the menu text a little smaller, and perhaps set it in Times to make it a little closer to the SIFR enabled version. (I'd also move the [contact us] link to somewhere more prominent, if I were looking at this on my phone it'd almost certainly be to find the address or phone number, thats pretty well hidden information when browsing that site in a small screen)